Google Appsheet not displaying Image from google sheet Image URL column
I have a google sheet column that contain Image URL from a google drive (refer Image1).
The Google Drive folder where the images saved are set as viewable by "Anyone with the link" (refer Image2).
Image 1

Image 2

In the google Appsheet, the "Image" column type is set as "Image" and also tried with "Show"

Under the view, I have set "Main Image" as "Image" column.

I have been trying to follow the post below to resolve this issue but still not working:

Help with static image from Google drive and Use data from Google Drive
Base on this post, I have ensure my URL is in the format "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileID}"
Display images, documents, and audio files
I have turn off "Require Image and File URL Signing"


May I know how I can fix this?

In your situation, how about modifying the endpoint of the image file as follows?
From:
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id={fileId}

To:
https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?sz=w1000&id={fileId}


This endpoint is from this.
You can adjust the image size by w1000.
When the file of {fileId} is publicly shared, I confirmed that the image could be shown in the Apps Sheet by reflecting the above modification.


Thank you so much, it works!!!...Been exploring this since yesterday morning
